# MongoDB gives certificate not trusted while openSSL says keys is OK

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I have used `let's encrypt` to generate SSL certification. All the private key, chain and certificate is generated by `let's encrypt.

Now to use it in `MongoDB` I first merged `privkey.pem` and `cert.pem` into a file called `mongo.pem`:

```
cat /etc/dehydrated/certs/mongo.example.com/privkey.pem /etc/dehydrated/certs/mongo.example.com/cert.pem > /etc/ssl/mongo.pem
```

Now using `openssl` I converted `ca.crt` into `ca.pem`:

```
sudo touch /etc/ssl/ca.pem
sudo chmod 777 /etc/ssl/ca.pem
sudo truncate -s 0 /etc/ssl/ca.pem
sudo openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/ca.crt -out /etc/ssl/ca.pem -outform PEM
```

Now a file is created called `ca.pem` in `/etc/ssl` path. Finally I append chain file content to the end of `ca.pem`:

```
sudo cat /etc/dehydrated/certs/mongo.example.com/chain.pem >> /etc/ssl/ca.pem
```

Now to verify the key I used `openssl` is below:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile /etc/ssl/ca.pem /etc/ssl/mongo.pem
```

The output is:

```
/etc/ssl/mongo.pem: OK
```

It's good to note that I have done the same exact procedure on another server and it went all ok and MongoDB works as expected.

Now my `MongoDB` config is as below:

```
ssl:
    mode: preferSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongo.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/ca.pem
```

**NOTE:** My mongoDB is a single primary node in which replication is enabled (Use to capture changes on DB)

Now when I restart `MongoDB` it gives error below:

```
A member of a replica set enters RECOVERING state when it is not ready to accept reads. The RECOVERING state can occur during normal operation, and doesn’t necessarily reflect an error condition. Members in the RECOVERING state are eligible to vote in elections, but are not eligible to enter the PRIMARY state.

2018-05-15T18:26:00.171+0000 E NETWORK  [conn1] SSL peer certificate validation failed: certificate not trusted
2018-05-15T18:26:00.171+0000 W NETWORK  [replexec-0] couldn't check isSelf (mongo:27017) socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for SSL peer certificate validation failed: certificate not trusted
2018-05-15T18:26:00.171+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSLHandshakeFailed. Ending connection from 127.0.0.1:47454 (connection id: 1)
2018-05-15T18:26:00.171+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:47454 (0 connections now open)
2018-05-15T18:26:00.171+0000 E NETWORK  [replexec-0] SSL peer certificate validation failed: certificate not trusted
2018-05-15T18:26:00.172+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0] This node is not a member of the config
2018-05-15T18:26:00.172+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0] transition to REMOVED from STARTUP
```

Modules cannot connect to `MongoDB` and reports:

```
OperationFailure: node is not in primary or recovering state
```

Now I do not have access to primary node and it cannot show my dbs. When I disable SSL, everything works and node gets back to primary state. Why is this happening, while I have done the exact same thing on a node in another datacenter?

Comment: Is certificate done for hostname `mongo` with localhost address (127.0.0.1)? I don't think so... When you do rs.initiate, you should use hostname what is at the certificate.

Comment: @JJussi My certificate is generated for `mongo.my_domain.com`. When I issue `rs.status`, member name is set to `mongo:27017`! How should I change this replica hostname? Tnx. :)

Comment: "under the hood"... Start your mongod to maintenance mode (single instance, not replicaset). Go to  local DB `use local` and update system.replset collection document, members section. Then restart node back to replica set mode.

Comment: Where did `/etc/ssl/ca.crt` come from ?

Answer (score 2):

I changed hostname from `mongo` to `mongo.my_domain.com`. Moreover SSL keys are generated for `mongo.my_domain.com`. Mongo is now up and running with `SSL`.